# Distorted (robotic) audio recording on iOS using AudioQueue

Tags: ios, audio-recording, audioqueue

I'm using `AudioQueue` in iOS to implement streaming of recording to the web.

The problem is that it *usually* works quite well, but sometimes (~20% of my attempts) the sound is horribly distorted - it sounds robotic.

> **Edit:**
>   I am able to reproduce it quite easily on the ios6 and ios6.1 simulator - but I wasn't able to reproduce it on a real phone (ios6.1.3).

Attempting to debug it I save the PCM data to a file. The same distortion appears in the PCM file, so this is not a problem in the encoding or upload code. I've also tried to play with the number of buffers and the size of the buffers - nothing helped.

The problem is I don't know how to debug it farther - it appears the buffer is distorted  as input to the callback - before my code is activated (except for the audio queue config).

- do you have ideas what could be the problem?
- or how to debug it further?

**Queue setup code:**

```
audioFormat.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mSampleRate       = SAMPLE_RATE; //16000.0;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = CHANNELS; //1;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel   = 16;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame    = audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(SInt16); 
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket   = audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame * audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags      = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger 
                                  | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;

AudioQueueNewInput(
    &audioFormat,
    recordCallback,
    self,                // userData
    CFRunLoopGetMain(),  // run loop
    NULL,                // run loop mode
    0,                   // flags
    &recordQueue);

UInt32 trueValue = true;
  AudioQueueSetProperty(recordQueue,kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering,&trueValue,sizeof (UInt32));

for (int t = 0; t < NUMBER_AUDIO_DATA_BUFFERS; ++t)
{
    AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(
        recordQueue,
        bufferByteSize,
        &recordQueueBuffers[t]);
}

for (int t = 0; t < NUMBER_AUDIO_DATA_BUFFERS; ++t)
{
    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(
        recordQueue,
        recordQueueBuffers[t],
        0,
        NULL);
}
```

**Start recording function:**

```
pcmFile = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:pcmFilePath append:YES];
[pcmFile scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                       forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[pcmFile open];
setupQueue(); // see above
AudioQueueStart(recordQueue, NULL);
```

**Callback code:**

```
static void recordCallback(
    void* inUserData,
    AudioQueueRef inAudioQueue,
    AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
    const AudioTimeStamp* inStartTime,
    UInt32 inNumPackets,
    const AudioStreamPacketDescription* inPacketDesc)

    Recorder* recorder = (Recorder*) inUserData;
    if (!recorder.recording)
        return;
    [recorder.pcmFile write:inBuffer->mAudioData maxLength:inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize];
    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAudioQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we had the exact same issue in [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) Web Audio on iOS whenever a video element was present and the cache was empty.  Once cached, the problem went away.  We were unable to find a fix or a work around for the issue.

You can read the details in our community forum:

http://community.createjs.com/discussions/soundjs/162-ios-audio-distortion-when-video-element-exists

Hope that helps.